# How to simplify the formula for $n$th Fibonacci number when $n=2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, induction

When n is equal to 2 how do I simplify when the $n=2$ is put into the equation below
(by the way I have to prove this formula by induction that when n= any number it will equal that number)

$$F_n=\frac 1{\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n  − \frac1{\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n$$

This is what I did

When $n=2$ is added to the equation

$$\begin{align}F_n&=\frac 1{\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^2  − \frac1{\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt 5} - \frac{2-\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt 5}\\
&=\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt 5}=2
\end{align}$$

I don't know if this is right or not so, it would be nice if someone helps me to simply this formula to be (equal 2)

Comment: How did you get $4\sqrt{5}$ in the numerator there at the end? $(2+\sqrt 5)-(2-\sqrt{5})=2\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: I believe the numerator should read $(3 + \sqrt{5}) - (3 - \sqrt{5}) = 2\sqrt{5}.$

Comment: The correct statement of what you are trying to prove is that for all $n$ the expression gives the correct $F_n$  For $n=9$ you should get $F_9=34$, not $9$, which [you do](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%281%2Bsqrt%285%29%29%5E9-%28%281-sqrt%285%29%29%5E9%29%29%2F2%5E9%2Fsqrt%285%29)

Answer (score 3):

In the first line, $(1+\sqrt 5)^2=1+2\sqrt 5 + 5=6+2\sqrt 5$  Similarly $(1-\sqrt 5)^2=6-2\sqrt 5$.  Also the $2$'s in the denominators get squared.  It should be $$\begin{align}F_2&=\frac 1{\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^2  − \frac1{\sqrt 5} \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{6+2\sqrt 5}{4\sqrt 5} - \frac{6-2\sqrt 5}{4\sqrt 5}\\
&=\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{4\sqrt 5}=1
\end{align}$$  and in the [usual definition of the subscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) $F_2=1$

Comment: Perhaps the 2 in the denominator for $F_2$ should not be included in the parentheses so that the result becomes 2. $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{(1+\sqrt{5}))^n}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\frac{(1-\sqrt{5}))^n}{2}$

Comment: @PaulSundheim:  In the Wikipedia article, it is $\phi^n=\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n$  If the $2$ isn't squared, you don't get $F_2=1$ as you should.

Comment: @R0ss Millikan You are right, I was confused by the statement "...when n= any number it will equal that number". Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you factor out the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ you are left with difference of two squares so you need sum and difference of the terms in the parentheses, that is $(1)(\sqrt{5})$ then multiplied by the original factor taken out leaves F[2] = 1.